# Show/hide table row if specific cell is empty

Tags: jquery, html-table, row, hide

I have several tables on a page with various id's.  I have a checkbox on the page and whenever the checkbox is checked I'd like every single row (in all tables) with an empty td 4 to hide.  When the checkbox is unchecked I'd like to show all rows again.

I've searched around Stack Overflow and I've got some code (just trying to hide so far) but I can't get it to work.

```
$("#checkbox").change(function() {
    $("table tr").each(function() {        
       var cell = $.trim($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
       if (cell.length == 0) {
         $(this).addClass("nodisplay");
       }                   
    });
});
```

Edit: here is a jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6bfjw/

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Added jsfiddle to OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were just close.

I have implemented only hide part as question has done. You can do the rest.

**PROBLEM**: Selecting heading or `th` as well.

**SOLUTION**: Select using `tbody`.

Your working code should go like this:

```
$("#checkbox").change(function(){
    $("table tbody tr").each(function() {        
        var cell = $.trim($(this).find("td:eq(4)").text());
        if (cell.length == 0){
            console.log("empty");
            $(this).addClass("nodisplay");
        }                   
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6bfjw/2/)**